# Sending information through a dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, progressdialog

I want to pass with and intent.putExtra an int to another activity. I am inside a dialog that is inside a menu in the main class. My question is that how I do it because I dont know where or how to put it. This is my code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.numero_ejercicios_settings){

        dialogSpinner();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        i.putExtra(Constantes.NUMERO_TOTAL, numero_total);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}


public void dialogSpinner(){

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setTitle("Example");
    String[] types = {"5", "10"};
    b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            switch(which){
                case 0:
                    numero_total = 10;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numero_total = 10;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.numero_ejercicios_settings){

        dialogSpinner();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}


public void dialogSpinner(){

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    b.setTitle("Example");
    String[] types = {"5", "10"};
    b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
                case 0:
                    numero_total = 10;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numero_total = 10;
                    break;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NameOfActivityToStart.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constantes.NUMERO_TOTAL, numero_total);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    b.show();
}
```

Note i used `new Intent()`. if you use `getIntent()` u basically start the same Activity again.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh what do you mean by Error? you want him to start the same Activity as he already is in? wouldn't it be easier to just set the int directly then?

Comment: I dont want to start a new activity. Only passing the data

Comment: @DavidLamasJimenez So why you just don't give your activity a `setNumeroTotal` method. Why You need your info in the Activity's Intent?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh of COURSE there is no NameOfActivityToStart.class. Was just intendet as a Placeholder... but as it turns out OP doesn't really need to start Activitys

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh OP should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Define it final

```
final Intent intent = new Intent()
```

and you can putExtra afterwards. But you can't initialise second time

Comment: he just wanted to intent.putExtra inside dialog's clicklistener,which he can change the value with switch-case. Btw it is very nice manners , giving downvote, it encourages people to help this community.

Comment: From where do you know what OP wanted? why do you make your `new Intent()` final? Your answer wasn't a solution to anything. If he 'just wants to put intentExtra, why he shouldn't just use `getIntent()`? look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. Your answer is clearly not solving any problem